# ng-model preventing checked="checked" to select radio button by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

When I use checked="checked" ng-model prevents the radio button from being selected by default. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
<input type="radio" name="unitMiles" checked="checked" id="unitMiles" value="Miles" ng-model="unit" ng-change='nextActivityStep(3)'>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ngChecked` -- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked

Comment: @tymeJV - make that an answer. It's correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be using the `ngChecked` directive that comes with Angular.

Doc:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked

Comment: This may have changed in the two years since posting, but using ngChecked and ngModel on the same element generally shouldn't be done. You now have two directives vying for control of the element's value. The docs also recommend against this (see the link in the answer): "Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior."

Answer (score 5):

You can set your model to the value of your input (`$scope.unit = "Miles"` in the case) or use `ng-checked="true"` in your input.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented on the accepted answer (as of writing), the ngChecked and ngModel directives shouldn't be used on the same element.

If you're using ngModel, then the checked status of the input is only a reflection of the model. To set your radio input to true by default, simply set the model accordingly.

Using the code from the OP, where the value is `'miles'` and the model is `units`, and assuming these are scope variables, you would do something along the lines of `$scope.units = 'miles'` in the associated controller (or wherever).